# CSS select first element with a certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the syntax for selecting the first element with a certain class? Please specify whether that method of selection is part of CSS3 or CSS2.1.

Answer (score 60):

If you need the first element with a certain class **among its siblings**, you can use

```
.myclass {
    /* styles of the first one */
}

.myclass ~ .myclass {
    /* styles of the others (must cancel the styles of the first rule) */
}
```

Don't try to use `.myclass:not(.myclass ~ .myclass)` to do this in only one rule, it won't work since `:not()` only accepts simple selectors in the parentheses.

If you want the first `.myclass` in the whole document, there is no way to do it with CSS alone.

The `:nth-of-type()` or `:nth-child()` approaches posted are wrong, even if they coincidentally happen to match the elements you want in your page.

Browser support of sibling selector (~): IE7+ and all others.

Comment: Browser support is actually better than the CSS structural pseudoclasses. Edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Fail me... I just realized I had thought of this myself some time after you posted this, completely forgetting about your answer. I've credited you here now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107

Comment: do you know for the last element with the same class?

Comment: you save my day man, thanks!! just in case, instead of override, you can select the first one like this: .myclass:not(.myclass ~ .myclass)

Answer (score 0):

This problem sucks as bad as the solutions. IMO you should just give the first element a class of `.first{}` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 answer

You can now use selectors inside `:nth-child` and `:nth-last-child`. So if you have:

```
<div class="my-container">
   <div class="class1"></div>
   <div class="class1"></div>
   <div class="class2"></div>
   <div class="class2"></div>
</div>
```

Select the `div` with the first `class2` with this:

```
:nth-child(1 of .class2) {
  background: white
}
```

Or, if you want more specificity, this:

```
.my-container .class2:nth-child(1 of .class2) {
  background: white
}
```

Further reading:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo
- http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.testparent .test:first-child {
    color: red;
}

<div class="testparent">
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
</div>
```

the first div 'test' has red color only.

Comment: Um, no, that matches the first `p` of every `.test`.

Comment: And if the first child doesn't have `.test`, but some other sibling does, then nothing gets selected.

Comment: @ngduc It has worked for me using class names instead of element types. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
.class-name:first-of-type {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Comment: The `:first-of-type` selector applies to element names, not class names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type