# jQuery selector with nth-of-type()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Using Chrome Development Tools

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field')
```

gives me four instances of HTML Elements:

```
<div class=".proejct-text-field ...">...<>
<div class=".proejct-text-field ...">...<>
<div class=".proejct-text-field ...">...<>
<div class=".proejct-text-field ...">...<>
```

Trying the following doesn't return any Elements.

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field:nth-of-type(1)')
```

As for my understanding the first Element should be returned. I just use jQuery in order to find the right selector for my purposes and to take them into my css file. So How can I select the first Elment of those Divs. Btw: They are not wrapped into a certain parent element. So any child methods won't work. Further the number of divs is variable.

Comment: Why are you using `.` in `class` attributes?

Comment: You also misspelled "project".

Comment: @magic_al - You said in a comment below that you don't want to use jQuery. If your real question is "What is the CSS selector to select the first element with a certain class?" you should click "edit" and update your question, because having the jQuery tag and "jQuery" in your question title is confusing things. And if that _is_ your real question, it is a duplicate of some [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287272/css-select-first-element-with-a-certain-class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `class` name is incorrect, you are having a `.` in the <s>`class=".proejct-text-field ..."`</s>.

Also, you can use `.first()` to select the very first element like

```
$('.proejct-text-field').first();
```

You cannot select `nth-of-class` because there's no such way to select `nth` element with a `class`, so your selector should work though it doesn't because you have to take out the period `.` from the `class` name in your DOM)*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/czyzg/2/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/czyzg/3/) (Using jQuery `.first()`)

Comment: Thanks you seem to be the only one who understand, that I don't want to use jQuery. Still div.proejct-text-field:nth-of-type(1) dosn't do it.

Comment: The demo only works because all the elements have that class and the same parent. (You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/czyzg/1/) that it doesn't work the way the OP wants if you have more complicated html.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Obviously it won't, I've already mentioned it in my answer that `nth-` has nothing to do with `class`, OP also explains this.. *They are not wrapped into a certain parent element*

Comment: So what is the purpose of your demo? As it is, it appears to be doing what the OP wants but really it doesn't. Your answer says "you can use something like `div.proejct-text-field:nth-of-type(1)`", but now in your comment you acknowledge that that won't actually work, so...

Answer (score 7):

The [nth-of-type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) looks for element type, like `div, span` etc not for class name or any other selectors

use [:eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field:eq(0)')
```

or [.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field').eq(0)
```

Comment: Ok I did understand why it is't working my way. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can use `:nth-of-type` in combination with class name and other selectors.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes as an additional condition.... but the type counter is applied to the element type not to other conditions

Answer (score 2):

The [`:nth-of-type()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) *"Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent in relation to siblings with the same element name."* - But you indicated that your elements are "not wrapped into a certain parent element", i.e., they have no particular relationship with each other.

If you just want the first element with that class do this:

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field').first()
// or
jQuery('.proejct-text-field').eq(0)
// or
jQuery('.proejct-text-field:first')
// or
jQuery('.proejct-text-field:eq(0)')
```

Note that you should remove the `.` from the class name in your `class=""` attribute in the markup. I.e., it should be:

```
class="proejct-text-field"
```

(And you've spelled "project" incorrectly everywhere.)

Answer (score 2):

First change mark up with this

```
<div class="proejct-text-field ...">...<> <!-- removed `.` -->
```

instead

```
<div class=".proejct-text-field ...">...<>
```

And use `.first()` if you want first

```
jQuery('div.proejct-txt-field').first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a `.` in your class Name, that's unnecessary... Just make it `proejct`
Instead of `nth-of-child`, use `:eq`, like this

```
<div class="proejct-txt-field"></div>
```

and your jQuery

```
jQuery('.proejct-text-field:eq(0)');
```

or

```
jQuery('.proejct-txt-field').first();
```