# Removing a class by selecting the element through multiple classes and a method/selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched multiple different responses for *similar* issues - not the same and have tried a few different possibilities. (Links will be provided for what I've tried)

**Context:**

This is a personal project and for the purpose of this task, I am not allowed to touch the HTML code. I am trying to remove a class using JQuery to select its parent class with a [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)/[method](https://api.jquery.com/last/) `:last-of-type` or `.last()`.

Here is what I have already tried:

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
            <input class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" title="Username is a required field." type="text" value="" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" title="Password is a required field." type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
                    <span>Remember me?</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
            <button id="submit-signin-local" class="btn btn-primary" title="Sign In">Sign In</button>

            <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="/ForgotPassword" title="Forgot Password?">Forgot Your Password?</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**and JQuery:**

```
var lastForm = $('.form-group').last();
$(lastForm+' div.col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
```

The result from that code, is no changes to the HTML... The class still exists and is not removed. I believe the issue here is to do with the [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)/[method](https://api.jquery.com/last/). I originally tried

`$('.form-group div.col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');`

but looking at a bunch of StackOverflow responses, it didn't look possible to do so. [jQuery selector with nth-of-type()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782590/jquery-selector-with-nth-of-type)

I may be searching the wrong thing, so it is possible it is a duplicate - but after hours of searching - I doubt it

CodePen for anyone who wants to try - https://codepen.io/pen/ERjYXO

Comment: @NenadVracar Yeah, its under the bolded JQuery section in the post :)

Comment: I meant did you include jquery library in your codepen example?

Comment: @NenadVracar oh (facepalm) no I didn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
var lastForm = $('.form-group').last();
$('div.col-sm-12', lastForm).removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
```

this is my code with your given html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastForm = jQuery('.form-group').last();
    console.log(lastForm);
    jQuery('div.col-sm-12', lastForm).removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I just tried it in my CodePen and it doesn't seem to have worked?

Comment: Sorry my bad it worked. Nenad below mentioned I did not have JQuery in my CodePen!

Comment: Yes I did notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` method and select direct child `> div` of your last element. [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVNawx?editors=1010)

```
var lastForm=$('.form-group').last();
lastForm.find("> div").removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
```

You could also use selector like this

```
$(".form-group:last > div").removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this script

```
$("#submit-signin-local").parent().removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
        <input class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" title="Username is a required field." type="text" value="" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" title="Password is a required field." type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <span>Remember me?</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
        <button id="submit-signin-local" class="btn btn-primary" title="Sign In">Sign In</button>

        <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="/ForgotPassword" title="Forgot Password?">Forgot Password?</a>

    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<script>
$("#submit-signin-local").parent().removeClass('col-sm-offset-4');

</script>
```

Comment: Interesting take!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
var lastForm = $('.form-group').last();
$(lastForm).find(".col-sm-offset-4").removeClass("col-sm-12");
```