# select an element "inside" the :first-child pseudo selector using CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Good day all.

I have a problem, a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span><span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span><span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span><span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span><span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to select the first and last  that have selected on the parent... the pseudo code should be like this:

```
li.selected span { background: #FF4D6E; color: white; }
li.selected:first-child span{border-radius:30px;}
li.selected:last-child span{border-radius:30px;}
```

the problem is that the `span` is inside the collection of `.selected` so I would like to have the first `.selected`, and its `span`

Comment: This is not possible. There is the proposed `~` parent selector, but it is not implemented.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I do use jquery, but at this stage I must achieve this via solely CSS :/ too bad, but as always, very thanks for the help :D

Comment: some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287272/css-select-first-element-with-a-certain-class/5293095#5293095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible because `.selected` class element is not the first of its parent. But you can do a workaround here by using sibling selectors as shown below:

```
/* first child */
li.selected span{
    border-radius: 30px;
}

/* middle children */
li.selected + li.selected span{
     border-radius: 0px;
}

/* last child */
li.selected ~ li.selected ~ li.selected span {
     border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Above code is assuming you have only three `.selected` elements. If you have more and you know the count then change the last child code in the above with respect to the count. For example, if you have four `.selected` elements.

```
li.selected ~ li.selected ~ li.selected ~ li.selected span {     
     border-radius: 30px;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avLzhvno/1/)**

Comment: unluckily... this will be dynamic, so no way to know how many they will be :(

Comment: i'll accept your answer bcouse at least it shows a workaround :D

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' hey thank you man... you make me 10k :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then do this:

```
$("li.selected span").css("background" : "#FF4D6E", "color" : "#fff");

$("li.selected:first-child span").css("border-radius" : "30px");

$("li.selected:last-child span").css("border-radius" : "30px");
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I recommend taking a few hours to learn jquery.  [Here](http://try.jquery.com/) is a link to a good jquery tutorial.  You can finish this tutorial in about three hours.

Jquery allows you to dynamically select any element that you want and modify it in pretty much any way you can imagine.

This is the code I would use to modify the CSS of the first and last span elements with .selected parents:

```
var $childOfSelected = $('.selected').children('span')

$childOfSelected.last().css({'border-radius':'30px'});
$childOfSelected.first().css({'border-radius':'30px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first child you can use this

```css
li.selected span {
  background: #FF4D6E;
  color: white;
}
.selected:first-child,
:not(.selected) + .selected span {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>not</span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span>selected</span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span>selected</span>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <span>selected</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>not</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```