# How do I select the first class from a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```
<div class="role-main">
    <div class="abc">
    </div>
    <div class="bca">
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css part:

```
.role-maine .test:first-of-type {margin-left:0px}
.role-maine .test {margin-left:30px;}
```

So I do I assign de margin-left:0px for the first class, which has the name "test" ?

Comment: This is the website: http://latesthoes.mediaswitch.ro/. I am talking about the 3 iphone images at the bottom

Comment: Refer specifically to BoltClock's answer in the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

The selector that you are looking for seems to be `:first-child`, like:

```
.role-main .test:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
```

In this case and to refactor it, you could also do:

```
/* .role-main .test:first-of-type {margin-left:0px}
   Not needed anymore */
.role-main .test:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 30px; }
```

**EDIT:** In complement to the *@Popnoodles* answer, you name classes was different indeed. My code is fixed.

Comment: I already tried it , and does not work

Comment: That's because he has got typo in his code. He meant this code `.role-main .test:first-child { margin-left: 0; }`

Comment: I updated my code. I saw that mistake, but that not was the problem.Still not working :(

Comment: @AttilaNaghi just be aware of the lack of `:not()` support in browsers, as opposed to the support of `:first-of-type`.

Comment: Kyrbi thank you for your complement. As notified in my edit, @popnoodles already noticed this mistake in his post.

Comment: @Popnoodles If you don't consider an IE6 spec, the support is actually the same than `first-of-type`, as a CSS3 selector. http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot But both answers are actually correct.

Comment: I tried with not , but still not working.

Comment: Ah, I was reading the support for extended arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: @AttilaNaghi If any of Popnoodles or my answer works, we would need more details of your code (jsFiddle) because the issue should be more complex.

Comment: Again not the one to downvote but both answers are incorrect. User wants to select the first element which has the class `test`. As you can see in their code, the element which has class as `test` is neither the first child of its parent (it is the 3rd) and it is not the first of its type under the parent either (it is again the 3rd of type div).

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have got typo in your code. Your div has got in html class `role-main` but in CSS you call it `.role-maine`.

Answer (score -2):

only JS solution will help you here.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
el.style.marginLeft = "0px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z0jbpnaq/

this might be helpful to you all - [CSS select first element with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287272/css-select-first-element-with-a-certain-class)