# Lists and nth-child

Tags: css

I have a question related to lists and the use of nth-child.

I have two lists targetted by a selector, and am trying to access individual elements.

In my Fiddle exemple, I expected the 5th item to be yellow not cyan.

When a selector targets multiple lists, are they not combined into one list?

```
    ul li:nth-child(5){
            background-color: yellow;
    }
```

---

```
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>

    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1q66hwgg/

Thanks!
S.

Comment: try  ul li:nth-of-type(4) //your-num

Comment: _When a selector targets multiple lists, are they not combined into one list?_ - no, there are not.

Comment: This second answer of this link is on point I think - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is working like you want. This question:

> When a selector targets multiple lists, are they not combined into one list?

The answer is NO. Two lists are independent and if you target `ul li` you are selecting all `li` of all `ul` but not combined.

In order to combine more than one `ul` you need to remove dinamically the end of every `ul` except the last, and the start of every `ul` except the first.

## EDIT

I made a fiddle with a piece of javascript that helps you to combine all `ul`

https://jsfiddle.net/1q66hwgg/2/

The code:

```
var arrLi = [];
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function() {
        arrLi.push($(this).html());
    });
    $(this).remove();
});
var ul = $('<ul></ul>').attr({id:"ulid"}).appendTo("#wrap");
for(var i in arrLi) {
    var li =$('<li>'+arrLi[i]+'</li>');
    li.appendTo(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NO they aren't combined to one..
`ul li:nth-child(5)` selects the 5th `li` child of a particular `ul` and not combine all the `ul` and then selects the 5th child.

You can however combine the `ul` and then apply the desired style to the 5th `li` of the combined `ul` USING JavaScript. Here is the fiddle how I did this using pure JS - https://jsfiddle.net/1q66hwgg/6/

The code is -

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var li = [];
for(var i=0; i< ul.length; i++) {
    var item = ul[i].querySelectorAll('li');
    for(var j=0; j< item.length; j++) {
        li.push(item[j]);
    }
    if(li[4]) {
        li[4].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been through [CSS select first element with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287272/css-select-first-element-with-a-certain-class/5293095#5293095/) answer and `nth-of-child` and found this..please check

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1q66hwgg/4/)

*As Marcos and Paulie said*, two list will be independent and for both or all(if you use more) you have to apply different different CSS rules but if you want to go via one parent then you can go with my fiddle(help with Paulie_D and Lea). You can easily go with them with help of outer `div`/`ul`

Comment: can some one help me..how can i change this url in link which i gave in my answer..m fed up with this system of So..please edit the question and make it link..thanx

Comment: well i have to add blank div to add that demo..is there any option to link jsfiddle without adding any code snippet?

Comment: Well, i don't want to talk about meta.stackoverflow as damn bad exp with it..people there is like ready to give negative marks..meta is like ghost for me..nightmare... :( bt thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

Quick jQuery solution although it's ***very*** broad as a selector and it would be advisable to limit the selector further.

```js
$('li').eq(4).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>

</ul>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers has told; No, the lists isn't combined into one, when using nth-child.

Do you want the first `li` in the second `ul` to be yellow, using only CSS, you can use this:

```
ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1){
    background-color: yellow;
}
```