# How to set color of every 1st, 2nd, 3rd post in a list with Flask?

Tags: python, css, flask

I'm using Flask web framework with bootstrap, and for my enumeration of posts, I have a for each (post) in (posts) loop outputting the code for each post.

I want to make every 1st post one color, every 2nd post another, etc.

My instinctive approach is to declare an integer before the loop at 1 and then mod 3 that integer to decide which color to make the post, and then increment the integer.

However, Flask won't let me declare just an integer i = 0 like so

```
{{ i = 0 }}
```

That's probably glaringly wrong to people here, but I don't exactly get what kinds of things I can do with {{  }}.

Can anyone tell me if my approach is completely off and there is another easier way to do this, or what I am I doing wrong with my approach?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: ^ This, pretty much. Do this with CSS. Don't get your Framework involved.

Comment: Also, although we've agreed that this is the *wrong* way to do things ... instead of manually incrementing a counter, you can use `{{ loop.index }}` (or `{{ loop.index0 }}` to access the loop counter without having to maintain one yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to style, just use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul li:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<ul>
{% for item in list %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

For reference, review [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007342/lists-and-nth-child) for examples with `nth-child` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084318/2676531) as the highest-rated `nth-child` answer.

Comment: Awesome. Much better than my approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is best done using the CSS selector `nth-child`.  Use something like:

```
ul.striped li:nth-child(3n + 0) {
    background: red;
}

ul.striped li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    background: blue;
}

ul.striped li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Lists with `class="striped"` will now use three colours.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this for the sake of completeness. This isn't the only case where you might want to keep a counter from inside your template and although you're correct that {{ }} won't let you set a variable, Flask (jinja2) will allow you to use {% set  =  %}. As a result, you can achieve your desired result using the template system to conditionally assign classes and styling based on the resulting class names. E.g, to alternate between red and green rows:

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for i in my_list %}
  {% if count % 2 %}
  <li class="odd">
  {% else %}
  <li class="even">
  {% endif %}
  {{ i }}
  </li>
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

CSS:

```
li.odd{ background-color: #f00; }
li.even{ background-color: #0f0; }
```

This has the benefit of being IE8 compatible, though that's a very minor advantage nowadays. The main take-away point is that you can set variables in your template and there may be other cases where it can make sense to.